# A triangle $ABC$ is given with $CB=11$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

A triangle $ABC$ is given with $CB=11$. Let $D$ be the touchpoint where the incircle $k(I)$ touches $AB$. If $AC=CD$ and $\cos\measuredangle CAB=\dfrac16$, find the lengths of $AC$ and $AB$.

[image]

I don't think that $I$ lies on $CD$. So for the sake of clarity is $I$ inside $\triangle ADC$ or $\triangle BCD$? This does not matter for the solution, though. On my handmade drawing, it seems that $I$ is inside triangle $BCD$.

Let $AC=b$ and $M,N$ be the other two touchpoints where the incircle touches $AC,BC$, respectively. By the law of cosines in $\triangle ACD\Rightarrow AD=\dfrac{b}{3}.$ Then $$CM=CN=\dfrac23b\\\Rightarrow BN=BD=11-\dfrac{2}{3}b$$ This makes $AB=\dfrac{b}{3}+\left(11-\dfrac23b\right)=11-\dfrac13b$. By the law of cosines in $\triangle ABC$ $$\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{b^2+\left(11-\dfrac13b\right)^2-121}{2\cdot b\cdot\left(11-\dfrac13b\right)}.$$ This isn't very convenient to solve. Is there any other approach you think it's easier? Maybe without using $M$ and $N$ as the other two touchpoints? Thank you!

Comment: Uploading a diagram (e.g. a jpeg file) and inserting it into the document would aid mathSE reviewers.  See [this document](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/recommendation-enhance-the-mathse-html-markdown-help-article-re-images).

Comment: @user2661923, is it better now?

Comment: @Medi You obtain $b=9$ easily.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, using my work or something else?

Comment: @Medi Yes by your work, of course

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, we're talking about the equation in terms of $b$ (the last thing I wrote), right? I don't find it easy, though.

Comment: @Medi  Yes, it's right and easy to solve. I am ready to show

Comment: @Medi there are a few things you can do to make this simpler to solve. For example, note that $(11-\dfrac13b)^2-121 = (11-\dfrac13b - 11) (11-\dfrac13b + 11)$

Comment: @Medi  I posted. You just solved this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is fine but if you want to make it a bit simpler, use the right angled triangles in your diagram and apply Pythagoras instead of law of cosine in $\triangle ABC$.

Referring to your diagram,

$CH = \cfrac{\sqrt{35}}{6}b, AH = DH = \cfrac{b}{6}, AD = 2 \ AH$

$CN = CM = AC - AM = AC - AD = \cfrac{2b}{3}$

$BH = BD + DH = 11 - \cfrac{2b}{3} + \cfrac{b}{6} = 11 - \cfrac{b}{2}$

Now $BC^2 = 11^2 = CH^2 + BH^2 = \cfrac{35b^2}{36} + \left(11-\cfrac{b}{2}\right)^2 $

$\cfrac{b^2}{4} - 11 b + \cfrac{35b^2}{36} = 0 \implies b = 9$

Now you can find $AB$.

Comment: May I ask you if we can say where exactly is the point $I$? The first paragraph of my question.

Comment: @Medi yes we can say that it is in $\triangle BDC$ without solving the problem. As $D$ is the point of contact, we know $I$ lies on line perpendicular to $AB$ and passing through $D$. As $\angle ADC$ is acute, $\angle BDC$ is obtuse so $I$ will be contained in $\triangle BDC$

Comment: I didn't quite get that. How we conclude $I$ will be cointained in $\triangle BDC$ from $\measuredangle BDC$ - obtuse?

Comment: $I$ is inside $\triangle ABC$ and $\angle IDB = 90^0 \lt \angle CDB$ so $I$ cannot be to the left of $CD$, right? If that was the case $\angle IDB$ would be greater than $\angle CDB$

Answer (score 1):

You got: $$\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{b^2+\left(11-\dfrac13b\right)^2-121}{2\cdot b\cdot\left(11-\dfrac13b\right)}$$ or
$$b\left(11-\dfrac13b\right)=3b^2+3\left(11-\dfrac13b\right)^2-363$$ or
$$b\left(11-\dfrac13b\right)=3b^2+363-22b+\frac{b^2}{3}-363$$ or
$$11-\frac{b}{3}=3b-22+\frac{b}{3}$$ or
$$\frac{11b}{3}=33$$ or $$b=9.$$

Comment: May I ask you if we can say where exactly is the point I? The first paragraph of my question.

Comment: @Medi  Yes, $I$ is placed inside the triangle $BCD$ because $\angle CDA$ is an acute angle.